# Как настроить COMPASS на готовый проект PHP Storm

Tags: css, ide, phpstorm, sass, scss

Объясните популярно, как этот compass запустить в PHPStorm 9? Установил Ruby. Запустил какие то там команды. Вообщем чёто установил. Но всё это вне PHP storm сделано.
Проблема в том, что имеются готовые проекты. Под каждый проект выделен отдельный раздел диска. В проекте находятся папки CSS и SASS. В них куча готовых файлов, в которых имеются строки типа:

```
@import "compass";
@import "compass/reset";
```

PHP Storm выдаёт ошибку при редактировании SASS, ясное дело - так как не установлен COMPASS. Но как? Как его мне установить и натравить на этот проект? Вся информация с сети рассказывает как создать новый проект. В моём случае ни как не могу это использовать для себя это.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятнее всего вы не установили компас в ваш проект.

Но давайте по порядку. "Какие-то там команды" так не пойдет.
1. С сайта rubyinstaller.org скачиваем и устанавливаем ruby в систему (на маке этого делать не нужно).
2. Устанавливаем sass, для этого в консоли выполнить команду gem install sass
3. Устанавливаем compass, для этого в консоли выполнить команду gem install compass
4. Устанавливаем sass и compass в проект, для этого с консоли зайти в папку с проектом или открыть терминал в вашем проекте в PHPStorm и выполнить команду compass init.
5. В файле stylesheets/config.rb описаны все условия по которым действуют sass и compass.

Заглянем в него:
css_dir - output директория куда будут помещаться скомпиленные css
sass_dir - директория в которой вы будете помещать свои файлы .sass
images_dir - директория для картинок
javascripts_dir - директория для js
6. Далее, если нужно, в консоли выполним команду compass watch. Эта команда запускает автоматическую слежку за папкой sass  и при появлении изменения любого файла в этой папке она автоматически все компилит в папку css.

Comment: 1. Начиная с пункта 4, всё ломается )) Так как терминал в PHPstorm на запросы этих команд выдаёт: "compass" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: 2. В PHPstorm есть функции для наблюдения File Watcher, и так же настройки для плагина Compass. Мне бы с этой стороны сконфигурировать. Так как у меня много проектов, и в каждой свои SASS и CSS. По вашей схеме, мне надо для каждого проекта, проводить все эти манипуляции. А по факту - нужно то, чтоб при сохранении SASS файла, компилиолровался CSS.